# Group Solr results by class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I'm searching two models with Solr like so:

```
@query = Sunspot.search Location, Employee do
  with(:category_id, params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id].present?
  fulltext params[:search]
  facet :category_id
  order_by(:weight, :desc)
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
end
```

I would like to create two discrete objects from the results, containing matches from both models so I can split them up in the UI.

I'm currently doing:

```
@results   = @query.results.group_by(&:class)
@locations = @results[Location]
@employees = @results[Employee]
```

but that's not working. `@locations` and `@employees` are both empty. What am I missing here? If i debug @results, I see matches and they're already grouped by model. I just want to expose that to my view so I can split up results into hideable/showable containers. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have solr, so I can't assume exactly what @results looks like (I assume it's a hash).

With that assumption, the hash keys are either Symbols or Strings.

So try

```
@locations = @results[:Location]
@employees = @results[:Employee]
```

or

```
@locations = @results["Location"]
@employees = @results["Employee"]
```

One of the two of those (probably the first) should give you the information in each instance variable. The reason is that ruby will set the hash keys of class names as symbols. If the names were already strings, the keys will be strings.